# How to design database model for Ingredient and combined ingredient

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 kind of ingredient:

- Basic (Chocolate, Vani, Strawberry)
- Combined (Chocolate - vani, vani - strawberry, chocolate - vani - strawberry)

So is there any way that I can use only 1 table for it or any best practices for this problem?
I wanna create a CRUD app for it and really stuck when tried to design this model.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would have 2 tables. One for the ingredients with an Id amd Name

```
Id. Name
1   Banana
2   Choc
3   Vanilla
```

The other for the recipes with id and ingredient id

```
Id  IngredientId
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 1
4 2
5 1
5 3
Etc...
```

Notice recipe 1 to 3 only have one ingredients - the basic recipes

The other 2 in my example are ban+choc and ban+van resp. - the combined recipes